# Iterating through dataframe to produce chart title (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

Good morning,

I am trying to iterate through a CSV to produce a title for each stock chart that I am making.

The CSV is formatted as: Ticker, Description spanning about 200 rows.

The code is shown below:

```
df_symbol_description = pd.read_csv('C:/TS/Combined/Tickers Desc.csv')
        print(df_symbol_description['Description'])
        for r in df_symbol_description['Description']:
            plt.suptitle(df_symbol_description['Description'][r],size = '20')
```

It is erroneous as it comes back with this error: "KeyError: 'iShrs MSCI ACWI ETF'"

This error is just showing me the first ticker description in the CSV. If anyone knows how to fix this is is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: I sent you a screenshot in my comment to your reply.  I am trying to plot a title with a ticker description on a stockchart generated through python... see here. http://prntscr.com/eitjsb

Comment: and my CSV looks like this... http://prntscr.com/eitlc1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix the error, since it's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but we can have a look at the problem itself.

Consider this example, which is essentially your code in small.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"x" : ["A","B","C"]})
for r in df['x']:
    print(r, df['x'][r])
```

The dataframe consists of one column, called  `x` which contains the values `"A","B","C"`. In the for loop you select those values, such that for the first iteration `r` is `"A"`. You are then using `"A"` as an index to the column, which is not possible, since the column would need to be indexed by `0`,`1` or `2`, but not the string that it contains.

So in order to print the column values, you can simply use

```
for r in df['x']:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think that makes sense.  when I expand the dataframe so it has two columns I am receiving a similar error. http://prntscr.com/eitjsb The link shows what I am trying to do but I am obviously trying to only plot the individual description for the chart

Comment: That looks to weird to make sense of, but I edited to answer to show how to print the column values.

Comment: Thanks a lot... omg so close!.... I've got the title... problem is it isn't iterating! This is what it is supposed to look like.  http://prntscr.com/eitqkb.  But it is giving the same title to every chart

Comment: It looks like it is finding the final symbol description in the CSV and using that for the title for all the charts.

Comment: I think the reason is because I have that for loop within another for loop... would you mind if I post the bigger part of the code?

Comment: I am not in the position to mind or not mind what you do. I can only tell you that in general questions on SO should stick to [ask] and if they require code, it should be in the form of a [mcve]. So if you can provide a minimal example of your problem, chances are indeed high that someone can help you.